# Why we take decreasing order of finishing times and NOT increasing order of discovery times in kosaraju algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-traversal, connected-components

We take decreasing order of finishing times in $G^t$ (transpose of Graph G) to know whther the path exists in other direction as shown below. But why can'nt WE take increasing order of discovery time in $G^t$ as i feel it forces to take the path in other direction.

In below figure, in G we took path x and in $G^t$ we see for path y. But the same result i am getting if take in increasing order of discovery times.

[image]

Comment: short answer is that finishing times indicate the end of directed paths, but start times do not indicate the beginning of a directed path. You can start your DFS from anywhere.

Comment: Ok understood now. That's why we do, while topological  sort, arrange vertices in increasing order of their finished times instead of discovery time. So called discoverry time and NOT start time. thank you